# matplotlibを使わない棒グラフの作り方について

Tags: python

整数からなるリストを入力として受け取り，以下のように横向きの棒グラフをprint関数で表示する関数 print_row_dot_graph を作成せよ．という問題が分かりません。

例）print_row_dot_graph([2,1,2,1])
**
*
**
*
です。ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: リストから各要素を取り出す方法は分かりますか？ループ処理は書けますか？

Comment: 質問文で検索すると Yahoo! 知恵袋で類似の投稿が複数ヒットするので、何らかの課題でしょうか？ ([1つ目](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10245903270), [2つ目](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13265483163)) / 課題であろうと投稿自体は大いに構わないのですが、質問であるなら「何に困っているのか/分からないのか」を説明しないと、仮に回答が付いても質問者さんの理解を深める事に繋がらないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

```py
def print_row_dot_graph(values):
    for v in values:
        print('*' * v) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_row_dot_graph([2,1,2,1])
```